# VBA: How to select a specific webpage div based on class

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm looking to select part of a table (basically don't want the title, would prefer to leave off headers row too) I can't seem to get it to work.

HTML:

```
<table id="mainContent" Class="MainContent-Report" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
...
<div class="reports-area">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="reports-heading">...</tr>
<tr id="R211" class="Reports-LineOne">...</tr>
<tr id="R212" class="Reports-LineTwo">...</tr>
```

VBA:

this grabs the entire table, including title and column headers, and works fine:

```
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("mainContent")
```

but what I want to do is something like this, excluding the title and column headers:

```
Set ieTable = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("Reports-Area")
```

For what its worth, The number of rows in the report is dynamic.

I get this error:

> "Object Variable or With Block not set"

Comment: As the function name implies, `getElementsByClassName` can return multiple elements that you will have to parse in order to find the one you want.

Comment: Okay so now with Set ieTable = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("Reports-Area")(0) I am able to pull everything except the title - is there a way to edit selection this to remove the first row before I paste to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods you can use. I will show 3 for now.

---

**Filter with CSS selectors:**

You could start with simply using an [attribute = value css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with starts with operator (^) to target the classes of interest. I can't see the rest of the html so unsure if this will pick up additional rows.

```
Dim rows As Object
Set rows =  ieDoc.querySelectorAll("[class^='Reports-Line']")
```

An example reading your html (Slighly amended for parsing).... I isolate the rows of interest and combine their `outerHTML`. I add `<table></table>` tags either end and use clipboard to paste table to sheet

Requires reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, rows As Object, i As Long, clipboard As Object, s As String

    Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.html")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set rows = html.querySelectorAll("[class^='Reports-Line']")

    For i = 0 To rows.Length - 1
        s = s & rows.item(i).outerHTML
    Next

    s = "<table>" & s & "</table>"
    clipboard.SetText s
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub

Public Function GetHTMLFileContent(ByVal filePath As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim fso As Object, hFile As Object, hString As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set hFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)

    Do Until hFile.AtEndOfStream
        hString = hFile.ReadAll()
    Loop

    html.body.innerHTML = hString
    Set GetHTMLFileContent = html
End Function
```

---

HTML sample (needs tweaking but sufficient for demo):

```html
<head></head>
 <body>
  <table id="mainContent" class="MainContent-Report" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ... <div class="reports-area"> 
  </table>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"> 
   <tbody> 
    <tr class="reports-heading">
     don't want
    </tr> 
    <tr id="R211" class="Reports-LineOne">
     do want 1
    </tr> 
    <tr id="R212" class="Reports-LineTwo">
     do want 2.
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**Remove offending item with javascript**

The following shows using javascript to remove first row (header row) from a table:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AlterTable()
    Dim ie As Object, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, hTable As HTMLTable

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .parentWindow.execScript "var child = document.querySelector('#customers tr:nth-of-type(1)'); child.parentNode.removeChild(child);"
            'in your case .parentWindow.execScript "var child = document.querySelector('.reports-area table tr:nth-of-type(1)'); child.parentNode.removeChild(child);"
            Set hTable = .querySelector("#customers")  ' in your case use:  .querySelector(".reports-area table")
        End With

        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Remove offending item with HTMLDocument methods:**

Same thing but without javascript i.e. using methods of HTMLDocument direct

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AlterTable()
    Dim ie As Object, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, hTable As HTMLTable

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#customers tr:nth-of-type(1)").ParentNode.RemoveChild .querySelector("#customers tr:nth-of-type(1)")  'in your case use  querySelector(".reports-area table tr:nth-of-type(1)").ParentNode.RemoveChild .querySelector(".reports-area table tr:nth-of-type(1)")
            Set hTable = .querySelector("#customers")  ' in your case use:  .querySelector(".reports-area table")
        End With

        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can supply properly formed table html I can write something better.